# How to use @EJB in this remote context with JBoss 6.4

Tags: jboss-eap-6

I actually have problem with the annotation @EJB both with local and remote use. But in this question I would like to focus on the remote use.

In this experiment I use Jboss EAP 6.4.

In the image below I try to show my EAR-structure and where the problem occurs, **the red arrow**.
[image]

My code in RemoteCallSessionBean that should be injected looks like:

```
@EJB(mappedName="StatelessBean")
private static BeanRemote beanRemote;


public static String returnAString(String parameter)
{
    try
    {
        String string_2 = beanRemote.returnAString("RemoteCallSessionBean-remote-interface");
```

Question 1)
My problem is that beanRemote never get injected and I get a NullPointer at the last row above. Do I miss anything?

According to: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjf.html#girfl ...under section "Remote Clients" I think this should work.
In this case I run it all on the same machine.

Question 2)
If I would run this on different machines, where do I configure the host or server-IP for the client to know where to connect?

Do you guys see something that I have missed? 
Best regards 
Fredrik

Answer (score 0):

I have some progress.
I found three mistakes.

1)  I had dependencies that might have been in conflict with my target environment. Compare image below with previous one.

2) I used mappedName but I never got that to work, see image below what I did instead.

3) I marked my ejb-member/ejb-field as static, I can not explain why but that just not worked for me.

Hope this help some one.

But I would love to hear if any one know how to solve my question #2 in my first post.

Best regards
Fredrik

[image]